# Interacting with terminal while upgrading Ubuntu in GUI

Tags: ubuntu

I'm in process of upgrading a ubuntu to 16.04, and it's stuck on the
"Installing the upgrades" stage.
I can see that there is an interaction is required with the terminal hosted by the GUI installer, as you can see on the screenshot.
There is a warning about keyboard shortcuts and an Ok button, under the title of "Configuring keyboard-configuration".
I would imagine that a component installer needs to present this warning to a user, but how to click that button in the hosted terminal?

[image]

This ascii-art button does not seem to be clickable, and the Enter button does not work too.

Answer (score 0):

The terminal ascii ui widget displayed as part of installer GUI turned out to be functional.

I don't know why it did not work from the first time, but after clicking the window and pressing the Enter button the interaction proceeded the next screen, and worked normally from that point. Interacting in ascii mode just seemed a little bit unusual in a context of GUI.